# Input in *ngFor can not type smoothly Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

Below link is a sample code.

https://plnkr.co/edit/xmWMm0yjFemdXQzZpJad?p=preview

I have an object(test), which contain a number array(test.arr).

```
<div *ngFor="let v of test.arr; let i = index">
    <input [(ngModel)]="test.arr[i]" type="text">
</div>
```

Once I type something on input, it will missing focus.

BTW, the reason why using `test.arr[i]` rather than v, see ***"[Cannot assign to a reference or variable!](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8602)"***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/h36ywubOhvghCulfbk48?p=preview)

If you use `*ngFor` with primitive values `number`, `string`, ... you need to take care Angular is able to track identity.

You can use a custom `trackBy` function like:

```
<div *ngFor="let v of test.arr; let i = index;trackBy:trackByIdx">
```

```
trackByIdx(index, val) {
  return index;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You save my day!

Comment: This solved my problem too. I was trying to two-way bind to a 2D array with really odd side effects. Using trackBy fixed it all for me. Thanks!